# PowerShell: Starting the CLR Failed with HRESULT 8007000e

Tags: powershell, clr

I'm getting the following error when running PowerShell scripts on a remote server:

```
Starting the CLR Failed with HRESULT 8007000e
```

This is basically how I'm running/calling the scripts:

On the local server I'm running a CMD script that calls a PowerShell script to create a remote session to a remote server. In the PowerShell script I also call a CMD script to run on the remote server like so:

```
$Script = [scriptblock]::create("cd $BuildPath | cmd.exe /c install.cmd $apptype")
```

The install.cmd script runs on the remote server and calls a PowerShell script that executes a series of tasks.

```
powershell ./Install.ps1 -BuildNum %BUILDNUM%
```

After the tasks are complete, the PowerShell script then calls another PowerShell script to run a separate series of tasks. This is when I hit the above error, when the second PowerShell script is called.

This is how the second PS1 script is called from the first PowerShell script:

```
powershell "& {. $BinToolsSrc\PostInstallValidation.ps1 -BuildNum $BuildNum -Test 'True'; Run-Validation -App $App -AppLoc $AppLoc -Env $Env:ENV -Site $Site -AppPool $AppPool -Config $Config -EnvConfig $EnvConfig -DllPath $DllPath}"
```

What usually causes the type of CLR error that I'm getting and how do I resolve it?

NOTE: I do not get this error when I run the install script locally on the remote server.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Installing PowerShell 3 on the remote server seems to have solved the problem as it targets the .NET 4.0 runtime.

Comment: `8007000e` translates to `Out of Memory`, so check if memory and disk on the remote host have enough free resources.

Comment: There is plenty of disk space and the memory peaked just above 1 GB. There is a total of 4 GB of memory on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem because I have changed some path settings in my VScode unknowingly.
I have changed the settings to command prompt which works fine for me now...(This might not be the best solution though).[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMGzI.png)